# Search for string while viewing a manpage

Tags: manpage

When viewing a manpage say `man ls`, how does one search the content of the man page?  (similarly, in vim you can call `:/search_string` what is a comprable command while viewing a man page?)

Comment: have you tried grep: man ls | grep thestringtosearchfor

Comment: I don't what changed but trying exactly what I wrote in my question I am able to search the content?  Maybe an update as part of the Mac OS 10.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which pager you use, which depends on your MANPAGER/PAGER environment variable. The [manpage of man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/man/) says:

> If MANPAGER is set, its value is used as the name of the program to use to display the man  page. If not, then PAGER is used. If that has no value either, /usr/bin/less -is is used.

Note that on Debian unstable the default is `pager -s` (managed by [alternatives](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)).
So, if you actually are using less, just type `/searchstring`, similar to vim.
See also the [manpage of less](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/less/) on how to navigate in less.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu (and probably similar distributions), you type `"/"` followed by what you want to search for

Example:

```
/word
```

Pressing `"n"` jumps to the next hit